# Springboot OIDC refresh token after expiration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, openid-connect, spring-security-oauth2

Im facing a problem which I cannot solve by myself.

I am using Spring Boot and Spring's **spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client** to connect to my IDP.
I configured my settings and when the User hits a @Secured endpoint, one gets redirected to the IDP's login form.
After successful login the User becomes redirected to the initial request and is now logged in.

This is all working fine until the requested token **expires**.

Now I was wondering if I can **refresh** the Token using the refresh token ?

Is there a way to do that ?

Thanks for any help.

Detlef

Comment: Do you get a refresh token from your IDP? Did you try to find some resources or documentation on the web which describe how spring oauth client handles the refresh? Remember that we're here to help you with a concrete problem.

Comment: Hi Michal, yes I get a refresh token. I could not figure out why there is no refresh request at all once the user token expired.